# flutter: workmanager and specific time with local notification

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I set notifications with the workmanager at a specific and special time (for example, at a certain hour the workamanger is triggered)
Note: I want to use it at a certain hour of the day and not use duration, for example, run the wrokmanager at 8 am daily.ur.com/NqZZA.png

Comment: You can use [flutter_local_notifications][1] package. 


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: i want the notification worked with workmanager (even the app terminated)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [initialDelay] parameter. The first trigger will happen after the initial delay and then it will repeat every day the "same" time.

```
// Calculate the Duration diference from now till the time you want
// to trigger the task    
    final initialDelay = targetDate.difference(now);
        Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
                       'workManagerTask',
                       'notificationsPeriodicTask',
                        frequency: const Duration(days: 1),
                        initialDelay: initialDelay,
                        existingWorkPolicy: policy,enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).